# Backup/archive Messages in iCloud

Tags: iphone, icloud, backup, messages-in-icloud

I want a complete local backup of all my iMessages. There are several apps that allow you to backup iMessages, but only what already exists on a device, which is only be a subset of the complete set stored in iCloud. [Neither iCloud backups nor computer backups include iMessages from iCloud](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204136).

I have 16GB of messages according to iCloud, but my phone only reports 8GB. Is there a way to force my phone or (ideally) Mac to download the entire message history, so it can be archived?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the only way I know of to force older messages to download to the iPhone from iCloud for Messages (iCloud Messages syncing) is to scroll up in the conversations you want to download on the Messages app. With a conversation open in the Messages app, tapping the time/battery status bar at the top will scroll a big jump up - that at least makes the scrolling go a little quicker.

I would love to know a better way, so I hope someone else has a better answer!